# How to pass a string from a managed C#/Xaml WP8 component to a D3D component?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, directx, windows-phone-8

My goal: To pass a string into a C++-written Direct3DComponent from a C#/Xaml-written Windows Phone Runtime component.

My understanding: This is accomplished using the D3DInterop.

To be more specific, I am using the D3D with Xaml application template and attempting to pass a value to the Direct3DBackground object that is created when the DrawingSurfaceGrid is loaded.

The template authors have accomplished this by copying over only trivial data types such as integers, but no examples of marshaling strings is given. I have come to the conclusion that the end solution will be more complicated than a simple variable assignment, such as a first call to first allocate a large enough buffer, then a second to actually copy in the bytes.

Below is first the managed part of the project which is passing data over to the D3DComponent and afterwards is the class Direct3DBackground class declaration that receives the data.

```
    private void DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_d3dBackground == null)
        {
            m_d3dBackground = new Direct3DBackground();

            // Set window bounds in dips
            m_d3dBackground.WindowBounds = new Windows.Foundation.Size(
                (float)Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth,
                (float)Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight
                );

            // Set native resolution in pixels
            m_d3dBackground.NativeResolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(
                (float)Math.Floor(Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth * Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor / 100.0f + 0.5f),
                (float)Math.Floor(Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight * Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor / 100.0f + 0.5f)
                );

            // Set render resolution to the full native resolution
            m_d3dBackground.RenderResolution = m_d3dBackground.NativeResolution;

            // Get the location of the model from the query string
            string ModelLocation;
            if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("ModelLocation"))
            {
                ModelLocation = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["ModelLocation"];
            }

            // then somehow pass the value of ModelLocation to m_d3dBackground
            /// ???

            // Hook-up native component to DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid
            DrawingSurfaceBackground.SetBackgroundContentProvider(m_d3dBackground.CreateContentProvider());
            DrawingSurfaceBackground.SetBackgroundManipulationHandler(m_d3dBackground);
        }
    }
```

And the C++ class that receives this data:

```
public ref class Direct3DBackground sealed : public Windows::Phone::Input::Interop::IDrawingSurfaceManipulationHandler
{
public:
    Direct3DBackground();

    Windows::Phone::Graphics::Interop::IDrawingSurfaceBackgroundContentProvider^ CreateContentProvider();

    // IDrawingSurfaceManipulationHandler
    virtual void SetManipulationHost(Windows::Phone::Input::Interop::DrawingSurfaceManipulationHost^ manipulationHost);

    event RequestAdditionalFrameHandler^ RequestAdditionalFrame;

    property Windows::Foundation::Size WindowBounds;
    property Windows::Foundation::Size NativeResolution;
    property Windows::Foundation::Size RenderResolution;
    // property System::String ModelLocationUri; // The solution is more complex than this

protected:
    // Event Handlers
    void OnPointerPressed(Windows::Phone::Input::Interop::DrawingSurfaceManipulationHost^ sender, Windows::UI::Core::PointerEventArgs^ args);
    void OnPointerReleased(Windows::Phone::Input::Interop::DrawingSurfaceManipulationHost^ sender, Windows::UI::Core::PointerEventArgs^ args);
    void OnPointerMoved(Windows::Phone::Input::Interop::DrawingSurfaceManipulationHost^ sender, Windows::UI::Core::PointerEventArgs^ args);

internal:
    HRESULT Connect(_In_ IDrawingSurfaceRuntimeHostNative* host, _In_ ID3D11Device1* device);
    void Disconnect();

    HRESULT PrepareResources(_In_ const LARGE_INTEGER* presentTargetTime, _Inout_ DrawingSurfaceSizeF* desiredRenderTargetSize);
    HRESULT Draw(_In_ ID3D11Device1* device, _In_ ID3D11DeviceContext1* context, _In_ ID3D11RenderTargetView* renderTargetView);

private:
    CubeRenderer^ m_renderer;
    BasicTimer^ m_timer;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is why you have `Platform.String` for passing strings around. Add the following property to D3DInterop class:

```
property Platform::String ^Name;
```

Now you can set it from C# code like this:

```
m_d3dInterop.Name = "Whatever you like";
```

Comment: Well, that could not have been any easier. I had actually tried this earlier but mistook a compiler error for a real one. Thanks

Comment: No problem, it is clumsy at best what they've done with the whole architecture. Fortunately, Platform.String = System.String :)